She's beautiful. She's gone to the market. How to differentiate "She is" and "She has"?
The contraction she's is defined as:
Ref. Cambridge dictionary

she's.

short form of she is:
She's a writer.
short form of she has:
She's been to Japan twice.


Though the dictionary cites two expansion of she's, I think "she is" is more popular than "she has".
Is the pronunciation same (homophones) for both the meanings of "she's"?
If yes, then how to differentiate what is spoken? Whether it is "she is" or "she has."?
Edit 1.
This is an old post from ELL, where they said that the reporter had made a mistake.

In the following podcast at 1:57 the reporter appears to say: "How is your life changed in the last few years?"

Isn't it possible that the reporter had said, "How's your life changed in the last few years?" and it was misunderstood as  "How is" instead of "How has"?
YouTube, Speakout: PreIntermediate Video Podcast Unit 7
"is changed" vs "has changed"

Usually context makes it obvious.

Native speakers rarely contract things like She's a nice smile. We might say She has a nice smile, She's got a nice smile, though. Note that uncontracted She has got a nice smile would normally only occur when refuting a claim that she has few desirable qualities, or similar "concessive" contexts.

@FumbleFingers At school we were never taught to contract, "She has". Can this sentence (question) be contracted - How's your life changed?

@FumbleFingers - my sister told me that as a teenager she had a friend of whom other girls said '[but] she's got very nice hair'.

The examples in your title answer the question for you - obviously she is not a smile.

@JamesMathai - if your local standard speech never contracts 'has' and 'have' then 'How's your life changed' can only mean 'how is your life changed?', which is correct, and means more or less the same thing,  but is rather old-fashioned and literary (see 'he is gone', 'she is come', etc).

That podcast question was very problematical and does not help your issue here at all.  Please edit that.

YouTube link https://youtu.be/df2rTTAmhpc?si=lBJyWOBDjizH-SAy&t=117 How about you? How is your life changed in the last few years. It's an error, a trivial slip, happens all the time. In an English test the question uttered by the presenter would be marked wrong. It should be HOW HAS your life changed in the last few years?

@Mari-LouA Thank you. I am not commenting on the video as I feel native speakers would be better judges.

So, you don't hear "How is..."? What do you understand her saying?

@Mari-LouA I learnt has can be contracted recently. To tell the truth How is and How's sounds the same to me. Perhaps others can spot the difference.

@Mari-LouA - How is your life changed in the last few years - why is that a slip? WB Yeats wrote 'All is changed, changed utterly. A terrible beauty is born', didn't he? Also, the Northern Ireland Sinn Féin leader Mary Lou McDonald told Keir Starmer "All is changed here and changing" in July when he visited Belfast. I know these examples are Irish, but it's not an Irish thing.

@MichaelHarvey will you be satisfied if I said "How is your life changed" is rarely said, and quite unusual in today's British English standard. And it will be marked wrong in an English language test, lest we forget this is an English language site for learners, many of whom aspire to take the IELTS or First Certificate English test.

In American English, we tend not to contract has|have when it is the lexical verb and contract when has|have is an auxiliary verb.
Southern US speakers tend to contract lexical has|have more than the rest of the country does.
In the US

She has a beautiful smile.

is far more likely than

She's a beautiful smile.


How's your life changed? I think "has" is an auxiliary verb so it can be contracted? So it can be, "How has life changed?

has is an auxiliary verb there, yes. "How's your life changed?" would be an idiomatic question in an informal conversation in AmE.

This is the same in BrE. Not just AmE.

@Lambie Not according to answers given on this site. "I've a dog".

That is not third person singular. He has a dog. does not become: He's a dog. even in BrE.

@TimR  I have edited my post with a link to another post, where this issue was debated. - has is an auxiliary verb there, yes. "How's your life changed?" would be an idiomatic question in an informal conversation in AmE

@JamesMathai The video isn't available any longer, so I don't know what was said. I think in the overwhelming majority of cases the speaker using the contraction in that particular question would be contracting "has changed", as  "has" is far more likely than "is" with that past participle.

@Lambie  The phrase "He's a wife and family" seems to be common enough.

No, that would just be a fast, connected speech rendition of: He has a wife and family.

@Lambie What is the difference between "contraction" and "a fast, connected speech rendition" ?

You have cited it. An actor or speaker could easily squish: He has a wife and family. together to make it sound like: He's, but in fact, it isn't he's.

@Lambie I don't know what you mean by "you have cited it" in response to my question about the difference between "contraction" and "fast, connected speech rendition". Are you suggesting a more precise definition for "contraction" than  the elision of sounds in which  two distinct syllables become a single syllable"?  Is can't a contraction but he's is not?

You  cited it: "He's a wife and family" I am saying again that they squish He has together so it SOUNDS like "he's".

@Lambie But couldn't you say "he's eaten already" is also just a form of "squishing"?  What separates the two, by your lights?

No, TimR. That is a regular, normal contraction used in the present prefect. Read my answer, I address this.

@TimR Mari-LouA has given the link to the video. I would appreciate your comments. Is it a British or American usage?

@JamesMathai I believe she says "My life has changed a lot in the past ten years."  It's not "My life's changed a lot" where "life's" is monosyllabic, and I do believe I hear a faint -h- at the onset of the second syllable. The vowel of "has" is quite far forward, almost but not quite like "hɛz"

@TimR The next sentence. Is it How is/! How's" your life changed in the last few years?

@JamesMathai "in the last few years" indicates that she means "has",not "is".  That temporal construction calls for the present perfect (auxiliary "has") not the copula.

Southern US speakers tend to contract lexical has|have more than the rest of the country does. = not true except at times in spoken English, not true re written English. He has a dog. does not become: He's a dog for the lexical have. It just does not. That does not mean it cannot be heard like that due to fast speaking.

@Lambie: I wrote  "Southern speakers" not "Southern writers".  Details matter.   And I think your "fast speaking" distinction is specious.  Southern speakers with a drawl even when speaking slowly may contract "I have" to "I've"   I've somethin' to say to you.

@TimR I lived in the Southern US and never heard that at all. Even so, if written (in a dialogue), it's still written. How else would one communicate it?

@Lambie  I don't disbelieve you when you say you've never heard the phrase I've somethin' to say but it is a very common phrase.  Just google it.

The pronunciation is the same whether the ’s comes from is or from has.
That said, the verb to have is not contracted if it is a main verb: “She has ten dollars.”
But it is often contracted if it is an auxiliary verb paired with a participle to form the perfect aspect: “She has found ten dollars” is contracted to “She’s found ten dollars.”

Can you provide reference "has" main verb is not contracted? How's your life changed? I think "has" is not the main verb so it can be contracted?

There are situations where BrE speakers will contract has even as the main verb. But as an AmE speaker I don't know exactly what defines those situations.

@ThePhoton - I think more formal or old-fashioned Brits (like the fellow I see in the mirror) are more likely to say 'I've fifty pounds in my wallet' than 'He's fifty pounds in his wallet', simply because the ambiguity of he's would introduce the kind of cognitive awkwardness that hurts the flow of conversation. Having said that, I think many people these days would probably see the avoidance of using 'got' as 'hoity-toity'. Our teachers at a State school from age 5 to age 11 (1957-1963) did their best to drum using 'got' out of us.

@MichaelHarvey But you wouldn't say: He's fifty pounds in his wallet. third person singular, would you? The s is contracted in the third person singular when the main verb is in the present perfect.

@JamesMathai This page covers the various uses of to have. It doesn’t say explicitly that only the auxiliary is contracted, but it only gives examples of contraction for the auxiliary. As for the second question, yeah, in has + changed the has is normal to contract. The has is an auxiliary and the changed is a perfect participle, so together they’re taken to be the present perfect.

LOGIC:
He has a dog. cannot contract to He's a dog without a meaning change. 3rd singular, that is,  without changing the meaning of the utterance in any English. So, apostrophe s for a verb signals the verb be. He's a dog.= He is a dog. [not a nice person].
She has a beautiful smile, cannot contract to: She's a beautiful smile. Because you cannot be a smile, except in poetic imagery.
Now, in persons other than third person singular (I, we,they, you), BrE speech does have: I've a dog. BrE speakers very often do contract the lexical verb have. AmE speech tends not to.
A contraction of have as an auxiliary in the perfect tenses is a different story. Have as an auxiliary often contracts in the third person singular (as well as other persons) in all varieties of English.

He's been here every day.
She's been cooking for the last hour.
They've been playing for ten minutes.

